# Issue with installing laravel on Windows 10 / Vagrant

Tags: windows-10, installation, vagrant

Hi I am trying to setup laravel with the following command: $ composer global require "laravel/installer" but I am getting the errors below

```
Changed current directory to C:/Users/Danny Younes/AppData/Roaming/Composer
Using version ^2.0 for laravel/installer
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/installer v2.0.1
    - Conclusion: remove symfony/console v2.8.49
    - Installation request for laravel/installer ^2.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/installer[v2.0.0, v2.0.1].
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/console v2.8.49
    - laravel/installer v2.0.0 requires symfony/console ~3.0|~4.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v3.0.0, v3.0.1, v3.0.2, v3.0.3, v3.0.4, v3.0.5, v3.0.6, v3.0.7, v3.0.8, v3.0.9, v3.1.0, v3.1.1, v3.1.10, v3.1.2, v3.1.3, v3.1.4, v3.1.5, v3.1.6, v3.1.7, v3.1.8, v3.1.9, v3.2.0, v3.2.1, v3.2.10, v3.2.11, v3.2.12, v3.2.13, v3.2.14, v3.2.2, v3.2.3, v3.2.4, v3.2.5, v3.2.6, v3.2.7, v3.2.8, v3.2.9, v3.3.0, v3.3.1, v3.3.10, v3.3.11, v3.3.12, v3.3.13, v3.3.14, v3.3.15, v3.3.16, v3.3.17, v3.3.18, v3.3.2, v3.3.3, v3.3.4, v3.3.5, v3.3.6, v3.3.7, v3.3.8, v3.3.9, v3.4.0, v3.4.1, v3.4.10, v3.4.11, v3.4.12, v3.4.13, v3.4.14, v3.4.15, v3.4.16, v3.4.17, v3.4.18, v3.4.19, v3.4.2, v3.4.20, v3.4.21, v3.4.22, v3.4.3, v3.4.4, v3.4.5, v3.4.6, v3.4.7, v3.4.8, v3.4.9, v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.10, v4.0.11, v4.0.12, v4.0.13, v4.0.14, v4.0.15, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7, v4.0.8, v4.0.9, v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.2, v4.1.3, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9, v4.2.0, v4.2.1, v4.2.2, v4.2.3].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.0.0, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.0.1, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.0.2, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.0.3, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.0.4, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.0.5, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.0.6, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.0.7, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.0.8, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.0.9, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.1.0, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.1.1, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.1.10, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.1.2, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.1.3, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.1.4, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.1.5, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.1.6, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.1.7, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.1.8, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.1.9, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.2.0, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.2.1, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.2.10, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.2.11, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.2.12, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.2.13, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.2.14, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.2.2, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.2.3, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.2.4, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.2.5, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.2.6, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.2.7, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.2.8, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.2.9, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.3.0, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.3.1, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.3.10, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.3.11, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.3.12, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.3.13, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.3.14, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.3.15, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.3.16, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.3.17, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.3.18, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.3.2, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.3.3, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.3.4, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.3.5, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.3.6, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.3.7, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.3.8, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.3.9, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.4.0, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.4.1, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.4.10, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.4.11, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.4.12, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.4.13, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.4.14, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.4.15, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.4.16, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.4.17, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.4.18, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.4.19, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.4.2, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.4.20, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.4.21, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.4.22, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.4.3, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.4.4, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.4.5, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.4.6, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.4.7, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.4.8, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.4.9, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.0.0, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.0.1, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.0.10, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.0.11, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.0.12, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.0.13, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.0.14, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.0.15, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.0.2, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.0.3, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.0.4, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.0.5, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.0.6, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.0.7, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.0.8, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.0.9, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.1, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.10, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.11, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.2, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.3, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.4, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.5, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.6, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.7, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.8, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.9, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.2.0, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.2.1, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.2.2, v2.8.49].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.2.3, v2.8.49].
    - Installation request for symfony/console (locked at v2.8.49) -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v2.8.49].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Your help will be greatly appreciated

Thanks
Danny